# Синтаксический разбор: это ДОКАЗАНО научными экспериментами

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Какой частью речи является и какую синтаксическую роль играет слово *доказано* в следующем предложении:

> Это **доказано** научными экспериментами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тут *доказано* — сказуемое, *это* — подлежащее, *экспериментами* — дополнение, *научными* — определение.

Доказано — предикатив (краткое причастие в роли предикатива).

Comment: Тогда встречный вопрос. Словосочетание **научные эксперименты** может соседствовать с глаголом **доказать** (учёные в результате многочисленных научных экспериментов доказали что-либо). Каким путём глагол трансформировался в предикатив?

Comment: @ДенисКулагин _доказано_, строго говоря, ни во что не трансформировалось: оно как было краткое причастие (т. е. глагольная форма), так им и осталось. Следует говорить о предикативах как о классе _употреблений_ слов другой части речи, в данном случае кр. прич. Наверно, не будет большой ошибкой такая формулировка: _доказано_ — кр. прич. в роли/знач. предикатива.

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос как раз и возник из того, что есть все признаки предикатива, но за ним явно торчат уши краткого причастия.